# Error after transfering process to a new host

Tags: database

I transfered my website to a new host and I am seeing this error:

> PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146
>   Table 'teise1_katalogas.system' doesn't exist: SELECT name, filename
>   FROM {system} WHERE status = 1 AND bootstrap = 1 AND type = 'module'
>   ORDER BY weight ASC, name ASC; Array ( ) in system_list() (line 136 of
>   /home1/teise1/public_html/imoniukatalogai.lt/includes/module.inc).

Anybody who knows how to resolve this error?

Comment: Are you sure that the info about database in settings.php file is right?

Answer (score 0):

These kinds of problems (after transfer to a new host) might be caused by some type of permission problems. At least if we may assume that the table in the error message does actually exist (if not that needs to be addressed of course).

So I'd verify that the userid specified in the settings.php file, has the appropriate access to the Drupal database (also specified in settings.php).

Another option is to verify the various items mentioned in https://www.drupal.org/node/1308308

Answer (score 0):

Drupal stores all of your site's content and setting in the database. The 'system' table is a core table in Drupal, so if your web site was fully transferred, you should have it. It looks like your code is in place, but the the database wasn't, or was partially, transferred over.

It looks like you have the right user name and password since you're not getting a 'permission denied' error, so that's good. I would verify that you have your database migrated over.

Another possibility is that the database dump didn't finish with either the export from your old host, or possibly the import into the new host.

Answer (score 0):

**'prefix' => 'arthur_deco_',** ---> Simply add this line on your `settings.php`. This suggestion definitely solve your issue.

**Or**

Try to remove the field from `field_config` and `field_config_instance`.

```
drush sql-cli
mysql> DELETE FROM field_config WHERE field_name = [‘field_DELETED_FIELD’];
mysql> DELETE FROM field_config_instance WHERE field_name = [‘field_DELETED_FIELD’];
```

Clear cache after deleting i.e. `drush cc all`